# Hibernate Sessions in Quartz Job in Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, quartz-scheduler

**TL;DR:  Do I need to manually setup a Hibernate session around the Quartz job invocation?**

I have quartz scheduler running in Spring but have very strange behaviour when it comes to using Hibernate in the Quartz job.

I have JPA repositories, and using these as below works as expected.

```
Reservation reservation = reservationRepo.findOne(resId);
```

However, when I try to use this entity as follows I get the subsequent exception

```
User owner = reservation.getRoom().getOwner();
```

Exception:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

If I set the spring logging to `TRACE` I see some JPA/Transaction/Thread magic, but it seems like it's all sorted out per-call to beans used, and no managed hibernate session exists on the Thread.

Do I need to somehow craft a Hibernate session around the Quartz job invocation?

Comment: I think you using the `reservation` object that you are using in your `Quartz job` is loaded in the different transaction? Do you have access to `Hiberate Session` in the `Quartz job` that you can call `merge` method?

Comment: Your method needs to be transactional.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu thanks, but these two lines of code are next to each other, in the Quartz Job.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks, yes this is the answer.  I have a level of indirection, due to an EventBus implementation, which was causing problems with Transactional. Creating a transactional service to handle the Job has proved successful. Feel free to create and Answer and I'll accept it.